# Rails strong params handle in YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I'm making API documentation on swagger and using YAML.
This is my YAML code

```
swagger: "2.0"  
info:
title: Sign_up Api
description: This Will alow user to Signup.
version: 1.0.0
host: e9ea53234b75.ngrok.io
basePath: /customer_app/api/v1
schemes:
    - https
paths:
     /sign_up:
       post:
         summary: Return User Credentials After signup.
         parameters:
           - in: body
             name: body
             required: true
             # type: string
             
             schema:
               type: object
               properties:
                 email:
                   type: string
                   example: test123@gmail.com
                 password:
                   # type: string
                   example: test123
                 password_confirmation:
                   # type: integer
                   example: test123
                 name:
                   type: string
                   example: testabc
               
         description: User can be signup by providing the listed params & it will return a authentication token and other user params.
         produces:
           - application/json
           
     
         responses:
           200:
             description: User credentials.
               properties:
                 id:
                   type: string
                   example: 70020ed1-50fe-4c7e-afed
                 password:
                   # type: string
                   example: pasw123
                 password_confirmation:
                   # type: string
                   example: pasw123
                 name:
                   type: string
                   example: testabc
           422:
             description: The specified email is invalid (e.g. not following the syntax) or paswwords are not same or missing params.
           default:
             description: Unexpected error
```

and im getting my params in rails by

```
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password , :password_confirmation, :uuid, :name)
```

in this way I'm sending my params from the postman

[image: This]

and getting  this response

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"moon123@gmail.com", "password"=>"moon123", "password_confirmation"=>"moon123", "name"=>"moon123"} permitted: false>, "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"customer_app/api/v1/registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

but by using user[email] in YAML got this in a wrong way

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"user[email]"=>"test123@gmail.com", "user[password]"=>"test123", "user[password_confirmation]"=>"test123", "user[name]"=>"testabc", "format"=>:json, "controller"=>"customer_app/api/v1/registrations", "action"=>"create", "registration"=>{"user[email]"=>"test123@gmail.com", "user[password]"=>"test123", "user[password_confirmation]"=>"test123", "user[name]"=>"testabc"}} permitted: false>
```

I don't know how to edit my YAML to get the response as I got from Postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postman's "form-data" bodies are for requests with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. In OpenAPI 2.0, such requests need to have `consumes: [multipart/form-data]`, and the body fields are defined as `in: formData` parameters.

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
...

paths:
  /sign_up:
    post:
      summary: Return User Credentials After signup.
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: user[email]
          type: string
          format: email
          x-example: test123@gmail.com
        - in: formData
          name: user[password]
          type: string
          format: password
          x-example: test123
        - in: formData
          name: user[password_confirmation]
          type: string
          format: password
          x-example: test123
        - in: formData
          name: user[name]
          type: string
          x-example: testabc
```

Comment: i have another related que can to please help me ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65329550/how-to-use-swagger-with-rails-dockerized-project

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rails, sorry